# Getting "Error #1006: getChildByName is not a function" when trying to access a text label inside a button object

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a button called "SpotButton". I am adding multiple instances of this button to the stage programatically. Here is the code:

```
for(var i:int =0; i<myXML.hotspots.*.length(); i++)
    {
        trace(myXML.hotspots.hotspot[i]);

        var mySpot:SpotButton =new SpotButton();

        mySpot.x=myXML.hotspots.hotspot[i].@x;
        mySpot.y=myXML.hotspots.hotspot[i].@y;


        (mySpot.getChildByName("tooltip_text") as TextField).text="being set automatically";


        //mySpot.tooltip_text.text="being set automatically";

        hotspots.push(mySpot);
        hotspotToolTipText.push(mySpot);
    }
for(var j:int =0; j<hotspots.length; j++)
    {
        hotspots[j].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,hotspotHit);
        hotspots[j].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,hotspotMouseOver(j));
        addChild(hotspots[j]);

    }
```

On the following line:

```
(mySpot.getChildByName("tooltip_text") as TextField).text="being set automatically";
```

I am trying to set text of a text label used in the button object having instance name as "tooltip_text". But when I compile, I get the following error:

> Error #1006: getChildByName is not a function

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SimpleButton class does not have getChildByName function. Each state of button can be retrieved as DisplayObjectContainer object. The following code works:

```
((mySpot.overState as DisplayObjectContainer).getChildAt(1) as TextField).text = "My Custom Text";
```

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing what is in your `SpotButton` class it's hard to say, but I would probably guess that you need to cast your `mySpot` as a `DisplayObject`.

change your problem line to:

```
(DisplayObject(mySpot).getChildByName("tooltip_text") as TextField).text="being set automatically";
```

Answer (score 1):

Your class needs to inherit from DisplayObjectContainer in order to call getChildByName().
If your SpotButton class inherits from SimpleButton, then it wont be able to call getChildByName() because DisplayObjectContainer isn't in the chain of inheritance:

```
SpotButton > SimpleButton > InteractiveObject > DisplayObject > EventDispatcher > Object
```

Unlike Sprite, for example, on which you could call getChildByName():

```
Sprite  > DisplayObjectContainer > InteractiveObject > DisplayObject > EventDispatcher > Object
```

Comment: That is right, the base class is "flash.display.SimpleButton". Can you please tell me full path for DisplayObjectContainer that I need to write in the base class field?

Comment: flash.display.DisplayObjectContainer

Comment: It gives this error "Definition of this class could not be found in the classpath..."

Comment: I would use flash.display.Sprite because DisplayObjectContainer cannot receive click events. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Sprite.html

Comment: It gives this error "Definition of this class could not be found in the classpath..."

Comment: Make sure you import the Sprite class

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52477/discussion-between-umair-khan-jadoon-and-dene)

Comment: Actually, this is how I am setting the class imgur.com/Wd2Dd18
with visual interface I am sorry if this is a n00b situation.